# Inequation involving a sum

Tags: inequality, optimization, summation, asymptotics

I have the following inequality
$$\sum_{i=2}^l \frac{\log(i)}{\log \log(i)} \geq x.$$

I would like to find the minimum $l$ meeting this inequality. I am seeking an asymptotic equivalent for this minimum. I think that $l \sim \frac{x\log \log(x)}{\log x}$, but how to prove it?